# Get current action in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2 I could get the current action by using `$this->action`, but in CakePHP 3.x I can't use this anymore, as it returns the following error:

```
Error: actionHelper could not be found.
```

How do I get the current action in CakePHP 3?

Comment: `$this->action` was already depecated in 2.x!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$this->request->action`OR `$this->request->params['action']` both works.

Comment: It doesn't give the correct action name, only the second URL parameter.

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters

Answer (score 6):

In CakePHP 3.7 use:

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('action')`

Answer (score 5):

Starting from CakePHP 3.6 use non-deprecated `$this->request->getParam('action')`